# Unable to build using python-app.yml in git

Tags: git, continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions

I have a simple python application that will read json file from a folder path, create dataframe out it and test the schema of the dataframe. I am using python-app.yml in git actions to build and test it. I have also placed winutils.exe file and set the hadoop environment path.

[image]

But it is always failing in the build phase of git actions.
Error message while performing pytest. I have highlighted the folder path where it is reading json files

[image]

My pytest class is as below: -
[image]

"test_read_artifacts_path" function is getting passed but "test_read_json_file" is always failing. Inorder to check that I had used "test_read_artifacts_path" whether it is properly finding the file or not. But not sure when I pass the same path in "test_read_json_file" it is unable to read the json contents.

Please let know what is causing it to fail.

Content of my python-app.yml
[image]